# как сделать, чтоб ожидался ответ в телеграмм боте от пользователя

Tags: python, telegram

есть код который выглядит следующим образом, как мне в функции share_news сделать, чтоб ожидался сначала ответ, а потом уже отправлялось сообщение Спасибо ... :

```
def start(message):
def menu(message):
def share_news(message):
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Пожалуйста, поделитесь новостью и ссылкой на нее, "
                                          "после проверки мы ее опубликуем")

    news = message.text
    with open("info_message.txt", "a", encoding='utf-8') as file:
        file.write(f"{datetime.datetime.now()} - Пользователь {message.from_user.id} отправил сообщение: {message.text}\n")

    if len(news) != 0:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Спасибо, мы рассмотрим вашу заявку в ближайшее время.")
def last_news(message):
def channel_link(message):
def back_to_main_menu(message):

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def handle_start(message):
    start(message)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def handle_text(message):

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```